# Issues with CORS, Jquery and Coldfusion. Headers

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

I am using the following code to handle the jquery stuff:

```
var data = $('#loginForm').serialize();
alert(data);
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://devport.mywebsite.com/login.cfm?method=Login',
    crossDomain: true,
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    },
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function (xhr, testStatus, error) {
        alert(testStatus + " " + error);
    }
});
```

It is all time going to error, not sure why the problem is. The error is:

```
SEC7123: Request header access-control-allow-origin was not present in the Access-Control-Allow-Headers list.

SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.
```

The coldfusion side is like this:

```
<cfcontent type='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
<cfheader name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*">
<cfheader name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
```

Now the login function at bottom like this:

```
<cfif login is true>success <cfabort>
<cfelse>Fail<cfabort>
</cfif>
```

I have enabled core n jquery with:

```
$.support.cors = true;
```

something is wrong I am not sure what.

Comment: Check this post to make sure that you're not losing the headers elsewhere: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22487309/coldfusion-cfc-cors-and-ajax-posts